# jQuery-UI toggle speed seems always the same

Tags: jquery-ui

I've been trying to change the speed of the toggle effect. I have checked the documentation, but I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.
I have tried using numbers (ie 3000, 300) and text (ie slow, fast) but I don't see any difference. I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery-UI 1.8.18.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click (function () {
        $('.myDiv'). toggle ("bind", "", 3000);
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: blue;"> </div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Can anyone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duration comes as first parameter of `.toggle()` not as the third one.

`.toggle( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`