# Jquery UI efect - toggle slow speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

How can I set slow speed in a JQuery UI toggle effect?

I'm using "drop" effect:

```
$( "#articleleftmenu" ).toggle( "drop" );
```

How can I slow `toggle("drop")` ?

I think that is something like this: `$( "#articleleftmenu" ).toggle( "drop", { "slow" } );`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what is your problem?you have already stated your answer in your question

Comment: Possible duplicat [jQuery-UI toggle speed seems always the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007994/jquery-ui-toggle-speed-seems-always-the-same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read documentation more carefully.

```
$( "#articleleftmenu" ).toggle("drop", 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5RWzE/

Answer (score 2):

Try this
toggle(2000,'easing-function');

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass the object with spefic config llike this :

```
$( "#articleleftmenu" ).toggle( {effect:"drop",duration :"slow"} );
```